# Unity set default image sprite programmatically

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sprite, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to create inputfields in Unity 3D programmatically. I succeeded in this when running in the editor emulator, but trying to built into an android device just provides an error. "BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'AssetDatabase'." Apparently this AssetDataBase is only available in editor.

```
    inputFieldGO.AddComponent.<Image>();
    var image : Image = inputFieldGO.GetComponent.<Image>();
    image.sprite = AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource.<Sprite>("UI/Skin/InputFieldBackground.psd");
    image.type = Image.Type.Sliced;
```

How do I get around this? How do I set the sprite of this image to the default InputFieldBackground entirely programmatically, without using the AssetDataBase? I'd move the InputFieldBackground into the project resources, but I don't know where the file is or if it's even accessible.

Answer (score 2):

AssetDatabase is an Editor class, that means that can be used in Editor but not in devices.

[Unity Scripting Reference For AssetDatabase](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html)

[image]

---

**Solution:**

Do you have your files on Resources folder?
Try this:

```
Sprite newSprite =  Resources.Load<Sprite>(spritePath);
```

From: [Unity Scripting Reference for Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

Comment: I tried image.sprite = Resources.Load("UI/Skin/InputFieldBackground.psd") as Sprite; since I am using UnityScript. This doesn't give an error, but also doesnt load the sprite. I don't know how I can access that sprite, without the AssetDatabase, and I can't move it to the resources folder, because I don't have the sprite!

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I can't set the default Input Field sprite, because I don't have default Input Field sprite. I don't know where to get the default sprite so I could move it to the the resources folder.

Comment: Ok, first you should put your psd file into your Resources folder, ie, Resources/UI/Skin/InputFieldBackground.psd
Then select your psd file in Unity and you will see its properties on Inspector, select Texture Type : Sprite (or Advanced). This will generate a sprite associated to your psd file.
Then try to load your sprite using: Resources.Load("UI/Skin/InputFieldBackground") as Sprite.

Let us know how it went !

Comment: Okay I tried this. Code to download sprite: "image.sprite = Resources.Load("sprite") as Sprite;" My resource folder: http://puu.sh/j2iMh/cbc332cebd.png  The rendered end result: http://puu.sh/j2iTy/2e09799e39.png  So it looks like its still not downloading the sprite. Changing the path to "UI/Skin/sprite" didn't help either.

Comment: mmm, weird... can you upload a screenshot of your Project view, showing your image file? ie:  http://snag.gy/50UDm.jpg

Comment: Mmm, I think something is wrong with your file, the icon of your "sprite" is an icon of a prefab. If you check my previous link, the icon of the image on your resurce folder should be like an preview icon, not like a prefab icon.